# Unexpected Exception Selenium IE Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I use visual studio 2010 C# with IEDriverServer.exe Webdriver version 2.42 on windows 7 32 bit OS.

In short I find an element and click it, the action completes fine (the element is clicked and causes the popup, which is not a new window, to close) but code appears to wait a while, and then throws an error (WebDriverException) on the Click() line.

It is almost as though it's unaware it completed its task successfully.

```
try
{
   popup.FindElement(By.ClassName("inbox_mainclose")).Click();
}

catch (WebDriverException)
{
}
```

I have no idea how to debug this while nothing appears to go wrong outside of the error, which causes my application to exit.

I'd love to hear from anyone who has encountered and or overcome this issue.

**edit for exception information.**

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was unhandled   Message=The HTTP
>   request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   `http://localhost:51989/session/e151b5bd-e473-4625-912b-aa2ba5c9e8de/element/c63f25fb-4b36-4de8-8474-aec538b84808/click`
>   timed out after 60 seconds.
>
> Source=WebDriver   StackTrace:
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest
>   request) in
>   c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line
>   150
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute) in
>   c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line
>   114
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute) in
>   c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\DriverServiceCommandExecutor.cs:line
>   73
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in
>   c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line
>   852
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.InternalExecute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in
>   c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line
>   745
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String
>   commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in
>   c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement.cs:line
>   810
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click() in
>   c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement.cs:line
>   336
>
> at site_test.Form1.myClick(IWebElement webel) in
>   C:\Users\eltegs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\site_test\site_test\Form1.cs:line 42
>
> at site_test.Form1.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() in
>   C:\Users\eltegs\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\site_test\site_test\Form1.cs:line 240
>           at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>           at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: System.Net.WebException
>          Message=The operation has timed out
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>                at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest
>   request) in
>   c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line
>   142
>           InnerException:

Comment: Well what's the full exception and stack trace? This is absolutely vital.

Comment: I have edit first post to include that info.

Comment: When an element is clicked, there is by default browser complete load gets executed with the click. In order to over come it, Use Click No wait and call a separate method to wait for browser complete load.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no ClickNoWait method available in to the IWebElement interface.

Comment: What version of IE this?

Comment: Using Internet Explorer 11.0.9600

Comment: You've correctly configured IE11 so that Selenium can work with it, as detailed here?... https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration

Comment: Yes, I had, all but one thing which was disable "Enhanced Protected Mode" in IE options advanced tab. This option was not present so I configured and disabled via group policy. The initial problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

After further research around the web, I discovered this to be a problem in other webdrivers too, including chrome and firefox, and has been around without being fixed for over 18 months.

My solution was to get a reference to the ("inbox_mainclose") child of popup element, pass it to another thread and perform the click on it there.

This causes the new thread to wait for a request timeout and my main thread to get on with its work.

I'm writing this as an answer as the problem is in the webdriver external library.